# "He left that fish for almost near death" or "He let that fish for almost near death"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, expression-choice

Recently I saw a video in which a person had a fish in his hand (in a bare hand without water). He kept that fish for sometime in hand and finally poured a drop of water to show how a drop of water is important and it saves life. The concept is OK, but I don't like the way he recorded that video.

I commented on that video "The video is nice, but to record this damn video, he left that fish for almost near death."

My question is:

Is it correct to say "he left that fish for almost near death" or "he let that fish for almost near death"?

Or is there any other better way to say that?

Maybe both sentence is wrong, I think.

Comment: It's hard to tell because 'for near death' is not at all grammatical.

Comment: Then what should i say @mitch

Comment: *Left it for death* is correct. *Let it for death* is not correct. *Left it for almost near death* is grammatical but not idiomatic - it doesn't sound natural, and it's not very clear what is meant by it.

Comment: The fish was in it's last breathe. That's what i meant there in the sentence. Is near-death not a correct word? Then what should i use there?  @dDrew

Comment: He, the person intentionally let the fish to die, but saved it at the last moment to show the importance of water. This is cruel and stupid way to show the importance of water i felt.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exacty you're trying to say (it is obvious the general situation). __'left for dead'__ is an English idiom which may or may not allow modification depending. 'He left that fish for dead' might be acceptable, but sounds pretty colloquial, almost like a country accent. But that means 'He went away thinking the fish was dead'. 'left for near dead' sounds weird because 'left for dead' is somewhat final and 'left for near dead' is sort of hanging in the middle, sort of confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mitch. I think Isobella's answer is right. I should have used this sentence "he nearly let that fish die"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"He left that fish for almost near death" and "He let that fish for almost near death" are both incorrect.

"He almost let that fish die" would be a better way of expressing this idea.

Here is an explanation of the relevant use of *[let](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/let_1)* from the Collins dictionary for learners of English:

> If you let something happen, you allow it to happen without doing
>   anything to stop or prevent it. *[V n inf] ⇒ People said we were
>   interfering with nature, and that we should just let the animals die.*

Answer (score 0):

> "he left that fish for almost near death" or "he let that fish for almost near death"

Neither, not so much because of the verb (left/let), but because of the adjectives in the sentence. Your original sentence uses an adverb (almost) with an adjective/noun (near death). This is both grammatically incorrect and unnecessary.

"Death" is a noun, "to die" is a verb and "dead" is an adjective.  To make this grammatically correct you need to use:

- Adverb with verb. Almost died. "His actions meant the fish almost died"
- Adjective with noun. Dead fish.  "He almost had a dead fish"
- Adjective with noun. Near death. "He left the fish until it was near death"
- Adverb against verb (let). Nearly let. "He nearly let that fish die"

Saying that, I would choose "let", or allowed, or caused for the verb. It would be technically correct to put the adverb "nearly" with the verb "left", however "nearly left" doesn't really work.  "He nearly left the fish" doesn't work.  You either leave something or you do not.  You *don't generally* "nearly lose" your pen, you *wouldn't often use* "nearly leave" your car.  You generally either leave/lost it, or you do not.

Comment: "I nearly lost my pen; it fell underneath the couch". "I nearly left my car without the parking break on."

Comment: @Mitch, true true!

Comment: @Mitch brake or break? Lol

Comment: @Kris oops! haha